# Solr Http error: Http request failed. Could not resolve host:host

Tags: symfony, solr

It's my first time I'm trying to use SolrBundle in my symfony project istalled on xampp. Always when I try to use solr:index:populate I receive error mentioned in title of the post. What am I doing wrong? Many thanks for help in advance. Below my configuration

config.yml

```
fs_solr:
 endpoints:
    core0:
       host: host
       port: 8983
       path: /solr/core0
       core: corename
       timeout: 5
```

Comment: Your `host` should be `localhost`

Comment: Is your Solr instance hosted on the web server?

Comment: DrKey -I exchanged host to localhost and now error message is "problem accessing /solr/core0/corename/update Reason:not found"

Comment: @Cyprien Aubry- What do you mean as "Solr instance"? I downloaded Solr package and initialized from my HDD. I also added SolrBundle to my Symfony 2.8 project.